# error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag android

Tags: java, android, xml

The project was working fine then suddenly this error appeared although i didn't add or change anything .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AppName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="18.15"
        android:textSize="20px" >

    </TextView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which error is occur ?

Comment: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag android

Comment: @user1936104 try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: i did multiple times to no avail

Comment: @user1936104 post your full stacktrace.

Comment: @PratikSharma sorry i am new to this what is stacktarce

Comment: @user1936104 paste your full logcat here.

Answer (score 0):

It does not give any error when I tried the piece of code.
Trying cleaning the project by using the clean option given by any IDE.